# Spring Data throws 'No aliases found in result tuple'

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

After migrating my Spring Data application from Gosling-SR4 to Hopper-SR1 release, custom queries that extends JpaRepository throws the following message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter.convert(AbstractJpaQuery.java:246) [spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:185) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter$1.convert(ResultProcessor.java:173) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:185) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:142) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:107) [spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92) [spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 113 more
```

Is there any new configuration for this version? What to do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was identified as a bug in this version, and will be resolved in Hopper-SR2 release.

Comment: Bug fixed, and waiting for date releasing.

Comment: @ElLordCode I am getting this error in Spring Boot 1.4.0 (released on Jul 2016). Any ideas?

Comment: Well, spring boot 1.4.0 includes Hopper-SR2 by default which fixes this issue. In the meantime,  I saw some guys talking again about this persistent error in Spring Data forum, but nothing was clear up yet. Take a look at that. In my project,  it has been resolved. Cheers!

Comment: This issue is still unresolved even in Hopper-SR4: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-984